# Web Api is throwing a 500 error

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2, kendo-grid

I have a Javascript Kendo Grid that I'm trying to get working with server side sorting using an MVC Web Api. Everything is working except the sorting. Here is the HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#gridTrades").kendoGrid({

            sortable: true,
            columns: [{ field: "tradeName", title: "Name", width: "250px" }, { field: "isActive", title: "Active", template: '#= isActive ? "<i class=\'fa fa-check\'></i>" : "" #', width: "100px" }],
            dataSource: {
                serverPaging: true,
                serverFiltering: false,
                serverSorting: true,
                pageSize: 3,
                schema: {
                    data: "data",
                    total: "total",
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            id: { editable: false, type: "number" },
                            tradeName: { editable: false, type: "string" },
                            isActive: { editable: false, type: "boolean"}
                        }
                    }
                },
                batch: false,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "/api/v1/Trades"
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my Web Api code:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/v1/Trades")]
public IHttpActionResult GetTrades(int page = -1, int pageSize = -1, int skip = -1, int take = -1, string[][] sort = null)
{
    var trades = new BusinessLayer.VipScheduler.Trades();
    var total = BusinessLayer.VipScheduler.LoadData.FromSqlStatement<Models.Settings.GetTradesReturnModel>($"SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM {BusinessLayer.VipScheduler.Trade.LgTableName}");

    trades.GetAll();

    var retval = new Models.Settings.GetTradesReturnModel {Total = total[0].Total};
    foreach (var trade in trades.OrderByDescending(z => z.IsActive).ThenBy(z => z.TradeName))
    {
        retval.Data.Add(new Models.Settings.GetTradesReturnModelData
        {
            Id = trade.TradeId,
            IsActive = trade.IsActive,
            TradeName = trade.TradeName
        });
    }

    return Ok(retval);
}
```

The problem I'm running into is with the sort parameter. If I take the sort parameter off completely, the Kendo Grid works just fine except the sorting does not work. If I leave the sort parameter on as I have it above, I get a 500 error:

> Optional parameter 'sort' is not supported by 'FormatterParameterBinding'.

Here is the request Kendo Grid is sending:

```
GET /api/v1/Trades?take=3&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=3&sort%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=tradeName&sort%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc
```

Any help on getting this sort parameter to work would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you want/need `sort` to be `string[][]` (a [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays))?

Comment: Why is sort a jagged array? It looks like (and quite rightly) that web api is freaking out because there's no sensible way for it to map from what is effectively a string in the request, to that structure. What is it you're actually trying to achieve? What form do you want the sort data coming into the action?

Comment: To remove error you can just make this parameter non optional (make it first and remove = null). Of course asp.net will not be able to bind that query string to it anyway, so it will always be null, but that is another story.

Comment: @crashmstr According to the [Kendo Documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource) and by looking at the GET request I posted, it looks like it sends it like this: `sort[0][field]: age` and `sort[0][dir]: desc`. It appears to send it as a 2d array.

Comment: @Evk - The problem with making the sort parameter non-optional is that Kendo doesn't always send the `sort` parameter. The parameter only gets sent if the user clicks on a column header to sort it.

Comment: But that is not a problem - it will just be null if not passed.

Comment: @Evk it's coming through as null, even when it's being passed. Here's the unencoded request: `GET /api/v1/Trades?take=3&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=3&sort[0][field]=tradeName&sort[0][dir]=asc`. Maybe I'm asking the wrong question. Maybe I should be asking how to handle a parameter type of `sort[0][field]=tradeName` in my Web Api

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about in my first comment. If you or someone else won't find a way - I'll try to help with that tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent error you have now - just make `sort` parameter non optional (move it to the beginning of parameter list and remove = `null`). If it fails to bind (for example, no sort is specified in query string) - it will have `null` value anyway, so there is no reason to have `= null` default in this case.

Now, your sort specification is split over multiple query string parameters:

```
sort[0][field‌​]=tradeName&sort[0][‌​dir]=asc
```

so to bind it to your model, you will need a custom model binder. First create class to represent sort specification:

```
public class KendoSortSpecifier {
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
}
```

Then custom model binder (this is just an example, adjust to your own needs if necessary):

```
public class KendoSortSpecifierBinder : System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder {
    private static readonly Regex _sortFieldMatcher;
    private static readonly Regex _sortDirMatcher;
    const int MaxSortSpecifiers = 5;
    static KendoSortSpecifierBinder() {
        _sortFieldMatcher = new Regex(@"^sort\[(?<index>\d+)\](\[field\]|\.field)$", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
        _sortDirMatcher = new Regex(@"^sort\[(?<index>\d+)\](\[dir\]|\.dir)$", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    }

    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(KendoSortSpecifier[]))
            return false;
        var request = actionContext.Request;
        var queryString = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
        var result = new List<KendoSortSpecifier>();
        foreach (var kv in queryString) {
            var match = _sortFieldMatcher.Match(kv.Key);
            if (match.Success) {
                var index = int.Parse(match.Groups["index"].Value);
                if (index >= MaxSortSpecifiers)
                    continue;
                while (result.Count <= index) {
                    result.Add(new KendoSortSpecifier());
                }
                result[index].Field = kv.Value;
            }
            else {
                match = _sortDirMatcher.Match(kv.Key);
                if (match.Success) {
                    var index = int.Parse(match.Groups["index"].Value);
                    if (index >= MaxSortSpecifiers)
                        continue;
                    while (result.Count <= index) {
                        result.Add(new KendoSortSpecifier());
                    }
                    result[index].Direction = kv.Value;
                }
            }
        }
        bindingContext.Model = result.Where(c => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Field)).ToArray();
        return true;
    }
}
```

And finally your controller method signature:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetTrades(
[System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinder(typeof(KendoSortSpecifierBinder))]
    KendoSortSpecifier[] sort,
    int page = -1, 
    int pageSize = -1, 
    int skip = -1, 
    int take = -1)
```

Now you have strongly typed model of your sort (except `Direction` can be represented by enum instead of string) and can use it as necessary to sort your data.

Comment: This solution didn't work exactly, but it led me to the path that eventually gave me the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you refactor your API method. Instead of feeding it route parameters, use a DTO like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetTrades(GetTradesRequestDTO model)
{
    // method body
}
```

This is a best-practice anyway, and model-binding issues are minimized. Also I'm not sure why you're giving default values of **-1** to your parameters. Instead use a zero-based index. This might be a personal preference but I'm not sure what is being achieved by these negative values. And finally your sort parameter needs a refactor too. It could be a list of strings, or a collection of strongly-typed models, each defining a sort action. i.e. `List<SortAction> sort;`. How you use this information and implement your back-end data access is irrelevant here.

Refactoring your action method, model-binding and parameter data types should resolve your issue. Although I'm writing this from experience and haven't actually tested your code on my machine.

Comment: The reason I'm using `-1` is because `0` could be a valid parameter and I needed to determine if the actual value of `0` is being passed in or if no value at all was being passed in.

Comment: Oh I see. cool, you could use nullable types too I guess. still have the issue?